# What splitscreen game modes does Modern Warfare (2019) support?

Tags: xbox-one, call-of-duty-modern-warfare

What game modes (campaign, online multiplayer, etc.) does the 2019 Modern Warfare game support for split-screen play?

The information I have been able to find on the internet is primarily pre-release speculation, but even post-release discussions don't provide an answer (e.g. [this discussion](https://community.callofduty.com/t5/Call-of-Duty-Modern-Warfare/Split-screen/td-p/11209021) on the Call of Duty website, which includes two contradictory statements - one indicating support only in campaign, and one saying online match-making only).

Answer (score 1):

You can play the [spec-ops or multiplayer game modes](https://www.shacknews.com/article/115023/how-to-play-split-screen-in-call-of-duty-modern-warfare) in local two-player split-screen. You are unable to play Call of Duty: Modern Warfare's campaign in split-screen, or play with more than two people on one screen.

The spec-ops game mode, often known as the co-op game mode, can be played in two-player local split screen without limitations. The multiplayer split-screen applies some limits on what multiplayer game modes can be played. Common game modes like Team Deathmatch or Domination are available, but alternate game modes such as Infected or Free for All are prohibited as having two players working together may provide an unfair advantage.

You can also play local multiplayer called "private matches" which pits you and your ally against each other or against bots using maps and difficulties you select. These private matches do not allot any XP to your multiplayer characters but are heavily customizable and can be played offline in split-screen.

Answer (score -2):

You can play this game with splitscreen in co-op mode only. You will not be able to use splitscreen in the other modes (campaign, multiplayer, etc.)

Comment: Yes to co-op but no to campaign? What is co-op then?

Comment: With co-op I mean the co-op missions you can do. There is no splitscreen in the normal singleplayer campaign.

Comment: Are the downvotes because this answer is incorrect? If that's the case, can anyone go a step further and provide a correct answer?

Comment: Yes it's incorrect, as of December 2019 you can only 'play' multiplayer splitscreen. The other 2 modes (co-op and campaign) prevent you from using splitscreen when you select them. There's also a bug which means it won't allow you to connect to the matchmaking service in multiplayer when in splitscreen.